# Multiple projects in git (subtrees)

Tags: git, ansible, git-subtree

I have a git repository that I use for our ansible configuration. The directory structure is this:

```
ansible
|---Site
`---Roles
      |---Common
      `---other_project
```

This is in git, and it is private as only my team needs access to this.

I would like to make `other_project` a separate repository so that it can be uploaded publicly. I think what I need is subtrees, and I have got this working.  My problem is with the workflow.  Normally I follow a work flow pattern like [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

The main point of this is that I have a development branch and a master branch.  Once a set of code is stable it is pushed into master with a `--no-ff` so that in master you only see stable releases and nothing in between.

How can I do this with the `other_project`. Is there a way to use branches for the subtree? How do I then merge one branch into another and swap between them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look to Git [Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

Regards.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot see how they would help. If you can point me to something that would help explain how they could work in such a work flow, or how to have separate branches, then I will look again.

Comment: I think it's exactly what you're looking for. `other_project` should become a git submodule. There's a link in my response.

Comment: BTW, that branching model looks terrible to me. No matter what, I'd never merge feature incompatible branches.

Comment: If I understand sub modules, they are for when you are using a project that is being developed elsewhere. What I want to do is have a project that I develop but make part of it available separaty if needef.

Comment: Why prevents you to have another repository for that project?

Comment: Branches/forks are a PITA with submodules. I went through this exactly with our Ansible setup. You constantly will have to fiddle around with where your submodules point to.

Comment: Nothing prevents me having another repository, but since it will be developed as it meets the needs of the major one, it would be nice to keep it in their, but also keep it separate so that othe rpeople can use it with out pulling the whole setup (which is private).

Comment: @udondan, did you ever find a nice solution?

Comment: Well, actually we still use sudmodules and all the pain they introduce. But I will look into replacing it with ansible galaxy when I find the time. (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

If I get your structure right, `other_project` simply is a role. Then you could use Ansible Galaxy to install it.

For this you simply need a `requirements.yml` in your Ansible root folder with some content like this:

```
- src: https://github.com/your/role
  version: master
  name: other_project
```

Then install it with `ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml`

See [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html#advanced-control-over-role-requirements-files) for details.